# If string contains with get getContents (JXL)

Tags: java, excel, jxl

**UPDATE: POSSIBLE SOLUTION POSTED BELOW BY MYSELF**

I need my program to read a cell. If it contains a specific string, lets say the name "Jacob", then it needs to execute a certain static function defined later in the code.

My IF statement will be nested in a while loop.

```
int currentRow = 1;
Cell cell;
Cell ncell;

while (!(cell = sheet.getCell(URL_COLUMN, currentRow)).getType().equals(CellType.EMPTY)) {

    String url = cell.getContents();
    System.out.println("Checking URL: " + url);

    ncell = sheet.getCell(NAME_COLUMN, currentRow);
    ncell.getContents();
    ncell.toString();

         if (ncell.contains("Jacob")) {
             String FAV = JacobFavFood(url); // A static function will be defined later for this
             System.out.println("Jacob's favorite food is " + name);
             Label cellWithFAV = new Label(FAV_COLUMN, currentRow, FAV);
             sheet.addCell(cellWithFAV);
         }


            currentRow++;

    }
workbook.write();
workbook.close();
```

**UPDATE: POSSIBLE SOLUTION POSTED BELOW BY MYSELF**

Answer (score 1):

```
int currentRow = 1;
Cell cell;
Cell ncell;

while (!(cell = sheet.getCell(URL_COLUMN, currentRow)).getType().equals(CellType.EMPTY)) {

    String url = cell.getContents();
    String NAME = ncell.getcontents();
    System.out.println("Checking URL: " + url);
    ncell = sheet.getCell(NAME_COLUMN, currentRow);

         if (NAME.contains("Jacob")) {
             String FAV = JacobFavFood(url); // A static function will be defined later for this
             System.out.println("Jacob's favorite food is " + name);
             Label cellWithFAV = new Label(FAV_COLUMN, currentRow, FAV);
             sheet.addCell(cellWithFAV);
         }


            currentRow++;

    }
workbook.write();
workbook.close();
```

I forgot I can define the string as was done with the url. This does work, and it is able to call on a static function. I am still wondering why .toString() didn't work, though.